# Start a Google Glass immersion app from remote site

Tags: android, google-glass

I developed an app in the immersion layout of the GDK. When I run the app from Android Studio it works like a charm. But I want to take the next step. I want to start the app from a remote manager application. This application is a simple website.

How can I start the app remotely from the manager app? I watched the demo app. But this are live cards though?

Comment: Is it an app or a website?

Comment: The manager 'app' is a website. Simon

Comment: Is it an APK or a website you can access with a browser?

Comment: Google glass --> Still with debugging, after development APK
Manager site --> Still html

Comment: What demo app are you referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it as follows:

I send a live card from the 'site' to the Glass. In the Glass app I created in the AndroidManifest.xml in the MainActivity an intent-filter with a scheme:

```
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="component.name.scheme" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

In the live card, I call the default action OPEN_URI. And I set the Payload to:

component.name://open//.....

Hope that someone is helped with this :)